# how to solve mysql master slave replication error

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave

am trying to configure mysql master  slave configuration
in centos 7 with mysql version 8
following the link  https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-configure-mysql-master-slave-replication-on-centos-7/
everything went fine without errors
but finally when check with > show slave status\G  in slave server
i got error

```
Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'replica@xx.xx.xx.xx:3306' - retry-time: 60 retries: 1 message: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xx.xx.xx.xx:3306' (113)
Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
```

xx.xx.xx.xx is the master server ip
DB is not replication due to the above issue
the ports are opened

any clues to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

First, check that you do not have a firewall problem and that the Slave host can connect correctly on **3306/TCP** port to the Master.

If this is ok, make sure that the "replica" MySQL user on the master have correct GRANTs and that you have executed a

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

after the :

```
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'replica'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx';
```

so that the commands are immediatly taken into account
(looks like this step is missing in the documentation provided)

Answer (score -1):

From slave:

#### telnet MASTER_IP 3306

Trying MASTER_IP...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out

From Master

#### telnet SLAVE_IP 3306

Trying SLAVE_IP...
Connected to SLAVE_IP

#### sudo ufw allow 3306

#### sudo ufw status numbered

SHOULD DISPLAY :

"     3306 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)   "

#### sudo ufw reload

NOW IT SHOULD WORK

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).